# Synchronized countdown timer with `NSTimeInterval` without skipping seconds? (presumably due to rounding)

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering if there was a clean way to do a countdown timer with Grand Central Dispatch (then display for example in a `UILabel`) that's synchronized to the system clock... based on a reference date? — So if my reference date is an `NSDate` that's 20 minutes from now, I'd have a countdown displayed in seconds (don't worry about formatting) that's synced to the system clock.

Just doing a quick version of this skips seconds every once in a while in case the update method call doesn't arrive on schedule.

To me this seems like a pretty basic question, so I'm looking ideally for a basic/clean solution besides increasing the update interval to be 10x or something.

---

Also,  the solution shouldn't use `NSTimer`.

Comment: Run a repeating NSTimer with an interval of less than a second, say half a second.  Each time the timer fires, update your label based on the time interval since your start (or finish) `NSDate`

Comment: Just saw that you don't want to use `NSTimer` - Why?

Comment: i think you should use `NSTimer`

Comment: The problem with `NSTimer` is that it requires retaining an object and then *that* holds a strong pointer to its target, which can create a retain cycle and overall seems a bit heavy for the point of just trying to call a method every second until stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive method like this:

```
- (void) updateTimer{

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval secondsToDate = [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.referenceDate];
    _timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f", secondsToDate];

    if( secondsToDate < 0 ){
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateTimer];
        });
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Timer triggered!");
    }
}
```

You just have to call it the first time, then it will update the countdown every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I specifically mentioned in the post: "To me this seems like a pretty basic question, so I'm looking ideally for a basic/clean solution besides increasing the update interval to be 10x or something." ... That's basically what you've done here.